# 'while' statement works differently when using optimization (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I have a problem with such a piece of code:

```
uint8_t var1, var2, var3, var4, var5[];
...
while ( ((var1 & var2) != var3) && (var4 < (sizeof(var5)/sizeof(var5[0]))) ){
... do something
}
```

I have an `-O3` (Optimize most) option in GCC. In this case the code works in some strange unpredictable way.
When I have an `-O0` (None optimization) option, it works just fine.

How to force a compiler with `-O3` option not to optimize just `while(...)` line?
I tried to use `volatile` inside, but with no success. I want to have `-O3` option on, but make the code working correctly.

**EDIT:**

Ok, this is the complete example code. May be it's my fault, but I don't see what the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


struct st{
    uint8_t     var1;
    uint8_t     var2;
};


int main(void) {

    uint8_t         k = 0;

    uint8_t         arr1[4] = {0, 0b11000000, 0b10000000, 0};

    const struct st arr2[] = {

            {0b11000000, 0b11000000},
            {0b10000000, 0b11000000}
    };

    printf("size of arr2: %d \n\n",sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]));

    while ( ((arr1[k] & arr2[k].var2) != arr2[k].var1) && (k < (sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]))) ){
        printf("k: %d \n",k);
        k++;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Run it with -O0 and -O3 and you will see the difference.

**EDIT2:**
The output with -O0:

```
size of arr2: 2

k: 0
K: 1
```

With -O3:

```
size of arr2: 2

k: 0
K: 1
k: 2
K: 3
```

I expect `k` should not be more than 2 with any `-O` option.

Comment: I'm more curious as to why `-O3` is breaking your code. Are you using undefined behavior?

Comment: Unpredictable sounds like undefined behavior, but we would need to see more code, the smallest amount of code the produces the behavior an [online example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) would be ideal.

Comment: Can you post a minimal compilable example that shows this issue? It would seem there is some mistake in the code you're not showing leading to some form of undefined behavior...

Comment: Take a look at the assembly code to figure out why optimization isn't working for the `while` loop, and then fix it.

Comment: I suppose the problem is either with the ... or with the ... do something.

Comment: Occam's razor. Don't blame the compiler. And note that `sizeof` is compile-time evaluated.

Comment: Also, be sure that you really need `-O3`, have a look at `gcc`'s manpage to see what flag it activates and if you really need them. `-O3` should be used only if you know what it does and that you need it, otherwise `-O2` is often fast enough.

Comment: your declaration of `var5[]` is a compile time error.

Comment: Try swapping the order of the predicates?  It looks like you're walking off the end of the array.

Comment: To mch: no, if I define, let say, "var5[2]" - it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's too much noise in the comments section:

As @Kevin said, your `while (B && A)` should be `while (A && B)` since `A` is checking boundaries and the statement is being executed from left to right until false. Thus `B` will invoke undefined behaviour when array index `k` is out of bounds before `A` is reached to evaluate to false and stop the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. But I really don't understand why (1 && 0) is not equal to (0 && 1)?

Comment: @cyclone125 Because of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: @cyclone125 The end result is that they both evaluate to false, however as I said in my answer, it gets evaluated from left to right and continues until one statement is false or it's at the end of the statement, thus all are true. `1 && 0` is `true && false(STOP)` while `0 && 1` becomes `false(STOP)` and the rest is ignored.